# JIRA - How to add flag to epic task

Tags: jira

How do you add flag to an epic task in JIRA?

On a normal task, you just right click it and "Add flag", but when it becomes an epic you dont get that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open the epic
- Click Admin menu
- Add field
- Add flagged field

Now you can flag it as Impediment (which is the default flag), see my screenshot:

[image]

We are using the Jira cloud version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any way to do this if I dont have admin rights?

Comment: Yes, ask someone who has admin rights. The field "flagged" needs to be added to the epic issue type, only admins can do this. Alternatively use labels to filter and find issues that you you want to monitor.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a flag to an epic if it is in a sprint or on your Kanban board. Just click it like you would a normal issue, select the three dots, and "add flag". I had to create a separate Kanban board with just epics to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any built-in solutions for flag in an epic. What you can do is create a custom field and a custom filter with that field in order to take actions on the flagged items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check out custom fields with custom filter

Comment: Custom fields also need admin rights.